# dependency upgrade and downgrade puzzler

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I thought I understaood dependency resolutions in rust, but clearly I dont.

I am working on a large project and it has this dep

```
 tempfile = "3.4"
```

cargo tree says

```
PS C:\play\gitui> cargo tree -i tempfile
tempfile v3.4.0
└── asyncgit v0.22.1 (C:\play\gitui\asyncgit)
```

(nothing special about this dependency, I was trying to resolve clippy complaints about multiple version of same crate and this was one of the crates pulling in a conflicting version)

When I run clippy I got

```
  error: multiple versions for dependency `windows-sys`: 0.42.0, 0.45.0
```

Some investigation shows that I probably should upgrade to 3.5

So i changed to

```
  tempfile = "3.5"
```

I now get a huge storm of multiple version conflicts. So I think OK I will go back to 3.4

```
   tempfile = "3.4"
```

but this is ignored, I am now stuck with 3.5. Cargo tree agrees

```
PS C:\play\gitui> cargo tree -i tempfile
tempfile v3.5.0
└── asyncgit v0.22.1 (C:\play\gitui\asyncgit)
    └── gitui v0.22.1 (C:\play\gitui)
```

OK so questions

- given that 3.4 can be replaced by 3.5 anyway why didnt I get 3.5 in the first place
- can I get back to using 3.4. So far I only found that deleting the directory and recloning works. Which seems a bit harsh

Further.

I have dependency on notify 5.1.0, that version depends on windows-sys 0.42.0 in its cargo.toml. This is one of the contributors to the version clash. But why doesnt it use 0.45.0 given that

- its a more recent version that matches 0.42.0
- I already have 0.45.0 in my tree for other dependeies

Comment: 0.42 and 0.45 are not compatible as far as cargo is concerned. See [semver compatibility](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/resolver.html#semver-compatibility) *"For example, 0.1.0 and 0.1.2 are compatible, but 0.1.0 and 0.2.0 are not."*

Comment: @kmdreko - well TIL. Its weird that 1.42.0 and 1.45.0 are compatible but 0.45.0 and 0.42.0 are not. I am sure people would think the first is 'version 1 point something' and the second 'version 0 point something'. In fact cargo treats 0.45.0 as 45.0. Odd, but it is what it is.

Comment: @kmdreko - i also worked out my first question, cargo.lock is the repo so the version are locked. cargo update fixes that. Still not sure how to go back

Comment: You can specify a specific version by using [`cargo update`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-update.html#examples) with `--precise` (i.e. `cargo update -p tempfile --precise 3.4.0`)

Comment: @kmdreko put that last bit in an answer so you can get your tick

Comment: I've linked an answer to explain how to set a specific version. Using `--precise` is a temporary solution since a `cargo update` would break it again. Using `=3.4.0` in your Cargo.toml is the better solution.